# Can't send messages with iPad Pro

Tags: ios, ipad, messages

I am having trouble sending SMS messages using my iPad Pro. I can send a blue iMessage to another iPad user but that's it - no SMS.

- Friends I regularly text using my iphone or iMac can't be reached using my iPad.
- I'm using the same wireless network but it just wont work.
- After I send a message almost immediately a red exclamation mark appears beside the message and a note in red that reads "Not Delivered".

If I click on red exclamation mark I just get a box the has "Try Again" message. Trying again just gives same result.

Does anyone know what I have failed to do that is maybe causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how-to-enable-sms-relay-on-apples-mac-or-ipad). The basics of the answer is in these steps.

1. make sure you're signed into iMessage on your non-iPhone device.
2. Jump over to your iPhone and confirm you're signed into iMessage and iCloud with the same account here, too.
3. Still on your iPhone, go to Settings > Messages > Text Message Forwarding.
4. Flip the switch to enable it on one device at a time.

This worked fine for me.

Apple's relevant support articles on the differences between iMessage and SMS messages as well as the full steps to enable this (with screen shots) are here:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207006
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201349